# MS SQL 2012 Sending Mail Error: Could not connect to mail server. (An invalid argument was supplied)

Tags: sql-server, email, sql-server-2012

I just run into an issue with Database Mail, but let me start with some basic information first.

Server is Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2012. Updates for both are recent up to about 4 weeks ago.
The server is intended to replace an older server where we have SQL 2012 on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

We try to send emails using database mail, having accounts and profiles set up exactly the same as on the old server. Every time we try to send an email, this is what pops up in the database mail log:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 5 (2017-08-29T09:27:59).
>   Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (An invalid
>   argument was supplied).)

Testing at the moment the code we want to execute (and which works on old server) is as simple as this:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @subject='test',
    @body='xcvyxcvyxcv',
    @recipients='recipient@domain.tld',
    @profile_name='Monitoring'
```

the SMTP server is the same as on the old server and it has no limitations regarding allowed senders etc. which could come into play here. We even stripped it down to anonymous sending through unencrypted plain SMTP for testing.
Also we have three different profiles configured using different Mail servers, same on all of them.

For testing we even set up SMTP server in IIS which works fine using the same SMTP server as Smart Host and using a Telnet client to manually send an email through the server works as well. Other than with these the error with database mail does not even show up in wireshark checking for SMTP.
Same with the Test Email button in database mail configuration as well by the way.

Windows Firewall is off.

Any ideas where to look, we went through about every bit and piece of configuration we could compare, security settings, user rights, but came up with nothing but the error message above which does not produce any helpful search results trying to look it up.
We also have no idea what could be the invalid argument, as even the built in test button throws the same error.

Any idea or help is highly appreciated

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this solved.

This link to [DBA Rant](http://www.midnightdba.com/DBARant/complete-troubleshooting-guide-for-sql-server-databasemail-dbmail/) got me to the solution.

At some point I checked the DatabaseMail.exe files security and added rights specifically for the service user, which got the thing running.